# Footer template in kendo combobox

Tags: kendo-ui

Does kendo have any option to set FOOTER template like header ?
My requirement is to show some content in Footer, say that "Type more for refine search"

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Combobox does not support footers.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/footer-template-in-combobox

> The ComboBox widget does not support footerTemplate. As an alternative
>   solution I suggest putting the checkbox outside of the widget and use
>   the setOptions method to modify the filter that is used by the widget.
>   For example:

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my requirement is not to change the Options. So I need not to setOptions. I just want to show some STATIC message(wording as I said in my last post) along with list